# Return value from SQS that triggers lambda function using aws java sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-java-sdk

I have created SQS Queue and event source mapping that triggers lambda function on receiving message. All this works fine and I am doing through aws java sdk.

Now I want to return value from Lambda function. How will I be able to access it as I am calling Lambda function only through SQS.Any help is appreciated

Below is my handler method structure:

```
public String handleRequest(SQSEvent event, Context context) {
.....
....
return "something"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because the  that sends a message to Amazon SQS completes once the message is sent. This allows the queue to be used to *decouple* services. In fact, a message could sit in an SQS queue for up to 14 days.

While the SQS queue will trigger the AWS Lambda function very quickly, there is still no concept of a "return" value from the Lambda function if it is triggered from an SQS message.

If you wish to trigger Lambda and wait for a response, you can [directly invoke the Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambdaClient.html#invoke-com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvokeRequest-) and await a response. This would not involve the use of SQS.

Comment: Thank you for response. It is clear to me now that it is not possible to expect a return value from SQS send message.

Comment: I need SQS for decoupling purpose. I have a lambda function that launches ec2 and deploys through user data. I want to invoke this through a machine to which I could give credentials that only has SQS send message access. I was trying to check if I could get back the instance id from it.

Comment: @Zara There are other alternatives which should be used to get inputs (not by returning them from that lambda), basically that lambda has to write/wire necessary to something like another SQS/SNS, storage like S3 or a DB. Lambda return values are needed by SQS to determine success of the Lambda invocation (to decide whether to retry that message or not).

Comment: Correction, a message can sit in a SQS queue for 14 days max, not for (more than 
 1) years.